# Определение номера записи в таблице

Tags: php, mysql

Всем доброго времени суток.

Есть запись в таблице, у которой id=90. `id` - это ключевое поле, все дела... но записи в таблице еще и удаляются, и id не совпадает с количеством. Охота определить номер этой записи. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(*) as `amount` from `table` where `id`<=90
```

*trollface* - не издеваюсь. Просто первое, что пришло в голову. Да и работает быстро.
На всякий случай: 90 - это просто ТОТ айдишник, который предложили вы.
Более общий случай:

```
function realRowNumber($id,$table){
  $sql = 'select count(*) as `realnumber` from `'.$table.'` where `id`<='.$id;
  $res = mysql_query($sql);
  $row = mysql_fetch_object($res);
  return $row->realnumber;
}
```

Comment: воспользовался первой конструкцией. спс